# WPF: Adding ContexMenu to Dynamically Created Tree

Tags: c#, wpf, treeview

Hi all I am trying to add ContexMenu into my Dynamically generated Tree.

Below is my Code For generating Tree.

I need to add ContexMenu for :

**NEW:
EDIT:
DELETE**

on MouseClick I should be able to perform the same operation of clicking the Respective Buttons.

Can any body help in completing the code.

**XML:CODE**

```
<Window x:Class="NewTree_DynamicNode.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525"
        Loaded="TestsTreeViewPageFunction_Loaded">
    <Grid>
        <TreeView Name="treeFileSystem"  >
             <TreeViewItem Header="Suite"  Name="MYTree" Tag="hi"  IsExpanded="True">
               <TreeViewItem    Name="treeFileSystem1" />                              
            </TreeViewItem>
        </TreeView>
        <TextBox Name="textBox1" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="121,150,0,0"  VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" />
        <Button Content="New" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="12,121,0,0" Name="button1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Click="New_Click" />
        <Button Content="Edit" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="12,150,0,0" Name="button2" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Click="Edit_Click"/>
        <Button Content="Copy" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="12,179,0,0" Name="button3" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Click="Copy_Click"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

**C# CODE:**

```
 private void TestsTreeViewPageFunction_Loaded(object sender, 
 RoutedEventArgs e)
        {

            this.MYTree.Items.Clear();

            for (int j = 1; j < 4; j++)
            {
                TreeViewItem Case = new TreeViewItem();
                Case.Header = "Case "+j.ToString();
                Case.IsExpanded = true;

                Case.Items.Add(Trythis());

                this.MYTree.Items.Add(Case);
            }

        }


        private TreeViewItem Trythis()
        {
            TreeViewItem Step = new TreeViewItem();

          for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
          { 
            Step.Header = "Steps " + i.ToString();
          }  
            return Step;          
        }



        private void New_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            textBox1.Text = "New Button Clicked";
        }

        private void Edit_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            textBox1.Text = "Edit Button Clicked";
        }

        private void Copy_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            textBox1.Text = "Copy Button Clicked";
        }
```

**EDIT:**

I am looking for a solution where I should be able to add or limit the ContexMenu to TreeItem based on there Header information.

Comment: Your code is really messy. Don't use `button1` names.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use style to set common ContextMenu property:

```
<TreeViewItem Header="Suite" Name="MYTree" Tag="hi" IsExpanded="True">
    <TreeViewItem.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}">
            <Setter Property="ContextMenu">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ContextMenu>
                        <MenuItem Header="New" />
                        <MenuItem Header="Edit" />
                        <MenuItem Header="Delete" />
                    </ContextMenu>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </TreeViewItem.Resources>
    <TreeViewItem x:Name="treeFileSystem1" />
</TreeViewItem>
```

Or you can add context menu in code: before line `this.MYTree.Items.Add(Case);`
you can add something like this:

```
var menu = new ContextMenu();
menu.Children.Add(new MenuItem{Header = "Save"});
menu.Children.Add(new MenuItem{Header = "Load"});
Case.ContextMenu = menu;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for replying....... Is there is any solution which will add the ContexMenu at Run time. So that Based on some calculation, Let's say based on Tree Header I will be able to decide which ContedMenu to Use